# Is possible in css/html to remove background of other element behind block?

Tags: html, css, background

I need to remove background of parent element behind inner HTMl div. 
I put example of code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf4pu5k7/10/) . 
There is `div.wrapper` , which has big full-screen background image. Than `div.container` inside wrapper has white background with opacity. Inside it there is small `div.form` which has blue background with opacity.

I need to remove white color behind `div.form`. Only blue opacity should be on background image at that part. 
Also it is responsive template, that's why i can not just use background with white opacity on image, with cutted area for `div.form`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why you dont remove the `background` on you `.container`?

Comment: @mmativ i need white background for rest area, around `div.form`

Comment: cannot understand your question, do you want to remove the white background behind blue box?

Comment: @DoughnutZombie yes, and left it for other part of  `div.container`

Comment: then remove background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);

Comment: @DoughnutZombie as i wrote, i need that background for rest of `div.container`. I need it to be removed only at small part of `div.container` - behind `div.form`

Comment: can you make a simple image what you want to do, just make in `paint`

Comment: @mmativ as i said in question, this layout is responsive, so `div.form` wouldn't be at certain position.

Comment: yes, we cant see your point, if you give an image of what you want, maybe we can help you. Because honestly we cant see your `point` for now.

Comment: @mmativ thanks, here is  [image](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=YsIZCxJSfcyIN0NwOEkp7XfuzNyEah) . Without white background `div.form` background is more clear, and has more details of background image of `div.wrapper`

Comment: @s_mart i updated my answer, check that

Comment: @DoughnutZombie i think you missed the `point`, compare the blue form in image and orignal fiddle, u will see that the image are more clearly see the texture background of `div.wrapper`, and the answer is not possible because form is a `child` of conatainer so you cant bypass the `background` of container.

Comment: @mmativ thanks, that was my point. sorry for not clear description.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.. i got it, you want to remove that small layer under that background image,
what you have to do is just control the parent div(.wrapper) as follows

```
.wrapper {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  background:url("http://jerodart.com/Jrod%20Images/Jerod%20Website%20Main%20Page%20Background.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0;
    height: 300px;

     overflow: hidden;  /*MODIFICATION */
    position: relative;  /*MODIFICATION */
}
```

From this

[image]

to this

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jf4pu5k7/14/